# Why did I get dtype 'object' on reading in my data frame?

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, types

I am new to Python, and I want to determine the type of each column in a data frame, I wrote the code below, but the results are not as expected, I only get 'object' for type.

This is my data frame (just the first 7 th column):

```
      IDINDUSANALYSE    IDINDUS IDINDUSEFFLUENT DATEANALYSE IDTYPEECHANTILLON   IDPRELEVEUR IDLABO  IDORIGINEVAL    CONFORME    CONFCALC    IDINDDOSS   CONFFORCE
  672   635 6740    10/01/13    2   1   3   1   1   1   531 0
  673   635 6740    11/01/13    2   1   3   1   1   1   531 0
  674   635 6740    14/01/13    2   1   3   1   1   1   531 0
  675   635 6740    15/01/13    2   1   3   1   1   1   531 0
  676   635 6740    16/01/13    2   1   3   1   1   1   531 0
  677   635 6740    18/01/13    2   1   3   1   1   1   531 0
```

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

with open("/home/***/Documents/Table3.csv") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)

df = pd.DataFrame().from_records(r)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(df.dtypes)
```

As a result I get this :

```
0      object
1      object
2      object
3      object
4      object
```

Please tell we what I did wrong ?

Comment: Please show your actual CSV file. If all columns were stored as `object`, it seems like they were detected as string, probably because your CSV file quotes each field. But post your actual CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/home/***/Documents/Table3.csv")
types = [df['{0}'.format(i)].dtype for i in df.columns]
print(types)
```

which results as

`[dtype('float64'), dtype('O'), dtype('O')]`

Considering your actual dataframe has 4 columns yet you got `object` as result 5 times, which was your first hint for you.

Comment: thanks for the response, i have just copied a sample from the data, so did not see that i have copied different sizes, but i try your code in the actual data i have, and i have this [dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('O'), dtype('float64'), dtype('float64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('float64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('float64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64')], but i don't understand whyi don't have the type DATE

Comment: i have changed the data sample @dragonfire__007

Comment: For the date issue, you have to use a date parser on the particular column which contains dates. You can try something like this :
`dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%y')`
`df = pd.read_csv("/home/***/Documents/Table3.csv", parse_dates=['DATEANALYSE'], date_parser=dateparse)`

Answer (score 1):

```
types = df.columns.to_series().groupby(df.dtypes).groups
```

Then print out `types`, and you would get all of the column types (grouped by type).

Also, you can open the .csv file directly to a data frame using: `pd.read_csv(filepath)`

If you want a specific column's type - `df.column.dtype` or `df['column'].dtype`

Comment: hey @David thanks for your response, i have this result, but can't seem to find the type date on it, it should appear since i have date type in my data {dtype('int64'): Index(['59', '2', '1', '163', '1208', '271', 
       ...
       '1875', '1876', '1877', '1883', '1886', '1887', '1888', '1902', '1903',
       '1905'],
      dtype='object', length=330), dtype('float64'): Index(['60', '1289', '1935', '335', '1547', '189', '1206',
       ...
      '1970', '1971',
       '1972'],
      dtype='object', length=388), dtype('O'): Index(['IDINDUSDEBITEFFLUENT'], dtype='object')}

Comment: It seems that your date is stored as an object. Please try printing out `df.DATEANALYSE.dtype`

Comment: i get this error : AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DATEANALYSE'

Comment: That's odd. Are you sure that there are no typography mistakes? And everything is in its correct case?

Comment: @ner `csv.reader` will read everything as strings (which gets classed as an object) - you don't want to be using that... use `pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')` directly instead and then you'll get a header row naming your columns and pandas will try and auto-type your columns where possible. So use literally: `df = pd.read_csv("/home/***/Documents/Table3.csv")` and then you can access `df.columns` and `df.dtypes`

Comment: @ner also - is your example shown the contents of your "csv" file? If not - could you show that?

Comment: @JonClements thank you for your response, it did fix my problem; yes i have put just a sample of the data, i have like 16000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Please show your actual CSV file. If all columns were stored as `object`, it seems like they were detected as string, probably because your CSV file quotes each field. But post your actual CSV file.

To read in quoted fields in pandas and convert them back to their type (numeric/categorical), do either of:

```
pd.read_csv(..., quoting = pd.QUOTE_ALL)
pd.read_csv(..., quoting = pd.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

and read the section 'quoting' in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

But also it's a good practice to explicitly pass `pd.read_csv(..., dtype={...}` a dictionary telling it which type to use for each column name. 
 `e.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32}`